# Is it a peculiar solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation : $y'=\sin(x+y)$ I found for $x+y \neq 2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},k\in \mathbb{Z}$: $\frac{-2}{\tan\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)+1}=x+c$..But...what's with $y=-x+ 2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},k\in \mathbb{Z}$ Is it a peculiar solution?

Comment: Do you have any boundary condition ?

Comment: No,there is no boundary condition!

Comment: I changed $sin$ and $tan$ to $\sin$ and $\tan$ and $pi$ to $\pi$.  Those are standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

$$\tan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right) = -1~ \mbox{for}~ x+y = 2k \pi-\dfrac{\pi}{2},k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

See what that does to your solution's denominator?

Note: I did not verify your solution to the DEQ, are you sure the posted solution is correct?

Comment: So,there is no $c$,from which we get $y =-x+ 2k \pi-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,so the $y$ is a peculiar solution..Or am I wrong?
I haven't also verified the result.. Here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3Dsin%28x%2By%29 there are other forms of the solution.. :/

Comment: Recall, we have the $\tan$ expression in the denominator. What if you swap $x+c$ and $tan$ terms? Clear? Also, the WA solutions do not appear to have any restrictions on them, so maybe you have an issue.